# ionic 7 @ionic-native/call-number/ngx when testing in ANDROID, returning plugin_not_installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic7

ionic 7 @ionic-native/call-number/ngx when testing in ANDROID, returning plugin_not_installed[image]

Added in app.module.ts file[image]

Added a function

When testing in ANDROID the this.issue returning plugin_not_installed.

Any help....

How to make this PLUGIN working

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a plugin to make a phone call. html supports this:

```
<a href="tel:+4733378901">+47 333 78 901</a>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_phoneto

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the actual plugin code with `npm install call-number`?

"Awesome Cordova Plugins" is the new of "ionic/native", they are wrappers around the cordova plugins to provide type-safety.

You should be able to list your plugins with capacitor (if using capacitor) `npx cap ls` in the project directory.